# How can i use 1 controller with 2 names in the same html file?

Tags: angularjs

I have controller conflict. I have simple form

```
<form name='regForm' ng-controller="SingUpController as form">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"
               ng-model="form.user.lastName">
   <favorite-dish favor-dish='singUpController.favoriteDish'></favorite-
  </form>
```

and my router

```
.state('public.signUp', {
      url: '/sing-up',
      templateUrl: 'src/public/sing-up/sing-up.html',
      controller: 'SingUpController',
      controllerAs: 'singUpController',
      resolve: {
        favDish: ['MenuService', function (MenuService) {
          return MenuService.getCategories();
        }]
      }
    });
```

How can i use `SingUpController` with names:

- "`form`" from "`ng-controller`="`SingUpController as form`""
- "`singUpController`" from component

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you need the controller twice on the same page?

Comment: I don't know how can I use it. Because I have  controllerAs:'singUpController', and "SingUpController as form". And controllerAs:'singUpController', I use when i send data to component, and also I need data from input to model.

Comment: Do you have 2 different components inside your page using the same controller? Or simply one component having a controller?

Comment: I have the feeling you could simply remove ` ng-controller="SingUpController as form"` from your html template, and always use `signUpController` instead of `form`. Is there a single reason not to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change to this

```
.state('public.signUp', {
      url: '/sing-up',
      templateUrl: 'src/public/sing-up/sing-up.html',
      controller: 'SingUpController',
      controllerAs: 'form',
      resolve: {
        favDish: ['MenuService', function (MenuService) {
          return MenuService.getCategories();
        }]
      }
    });
```

your controller need to be :

```
.controller("SingUpController",function(){
     var self= this;
     self.user = {};
});
```

and your html need to be:

```
<form name='regForm' ng-controller="SingUpController as form">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"
               ng-model="form.user.lastName">
   <favorite-dish favor-dish='form.favoriteDish'></favorite-
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two names for the same controller in the same template makes no sense.

If you already have the `user` property in your controller, you can use it as a model for the input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="singUpController.user.lastName">
```

If you want to access your input fields in the controller or in other places of your template (for example, for validating data), you should add `name="lastName"` to the input tag. After that, you can access its value from controller: `$scope.regForm.lastName` or from template: `regForm.lastName`.

If you don't want to use `$scope`, then just bind once in controller:

```
`this.regForm = $scope.regForm`
```

and then use `this.regForm`.